# Datetime.Now method in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datetime

I am using ASP.NET to provide some variables for the data that has to be added to a SQL database.

**Code I am using:**

I am using `DateTime.Now` to select the current time.

**How I use it:**

I have two pages, one is a page to insert the posts of the users. Other page is used for ajax purpose, to add some text comments to the posts.

In both page I use the same code.

But the code is executing different values. You can have a look here:

[image: DateTime.Now]

In the post the time is saved as "9/1/2013" which means 1st September, 2013! In comment it is saved as Sep 1 2013, which means the same.

**My question:** how does the code know that the request is an ajax one or the post one. The post page code is wrapped in `if(IsPost) {` however the comment is an ajax call.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I would assume the threads which process those 2 different requests are operating under different cultures, which would explain why they're being displayed differently (not sure why though, check your settings perhaps).

Comment: In case of storing Timestamp information of Post or any such thing, you should always store information as UTC time, and to display you should convert it to Local Time.

Comment: As I already mentioned, there is no time or other settings in my code in web.config or any other place, and Akash I can use UTC, but I don't want to do all that codings right now.

Comment: Hi guys, specially DavidN, I have rechecked the page, the page is executing the time as this: http://s10.postimg.org/tt9tguo95/datetime.png You can have a look here too. Its the code from the same page, I just wrote 5 more lines and made the page to provide me with the `DateTime.Now;` you can see the QueryString in the URL. The time was same as it was in the post.

Comment: Make sure you understand the implications of using `DateTime.Now` in a web app.  You really shouldn't ever do that.  Read [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the issue was.

I had set the column DataType to nvarchar(50) in the database table. After editing it to DataType DateTime I was able to get the same result. So the issue was not the Culture or DateTime. It was the DataType of the column in SQL Server Database.

Comment: That makes sense.  Never store dates as strings in your db.

Comment: Hehehe yes, :D I was saving the date as a string, and it was giving me this Result, I guess for this query `DateTime.ToString()` was being used as default.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your AJAX call is not changing the format string of your DateTimes, I would assume the threads which process those 2 different requests are operating under different cultures, which would explain why they're being displayed differently (not sure why though, check your settings perhaps). Try the following and you'll see how culture can effect DateTime output:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
Console.WriteLine (DateTime.Now.ToString());
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("gu-IN");
Console.WriteLine (DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Here's some [additional information on CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).

Comment: No, both files are placed in same folder, in same blocks "Almost". The only difference is that the first piece of code is placed in `if(IsPost)` and the other one is explicit. And also, I am not using any culture, not even IP or any thing like that. Just `DateTime.Now;`. I will try out this code.

Answer (score 0):

Code knows from Current thread's Culture information. You should use DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") or any other formate according to your needs to be sure of output.

Comment: But the question is why do the different threads have different cultures? This is inconsistent and will not only lead to issues with DateTimes, but things like numeric formatting, string comparisons, and a whole host of other issues.

Comment: Let me be straight forward, if you have a look in the code, in the first timestamp the month is single word, second one is three lettered word. That is gonna be an issue while converting it. @DavidN is right in his comment.